Looking for the eigenfunctions of the operator $T$ on $L_2(\mathbb R^+)$ defined by $Tf(x)=\int_0^\infty e^{-(x+y)^2/2}f(y)\,dy$
I'm looking to find a basis of eigenfunctions (and the corresponding eigenvectors) for the operator $T$ on $L_2(\mathbb R^+)$ defined by:
$$
Tf(x)=\int_0^\infty e^{-(x+y)^2/2}f(y)\,dy
$$
This operator looks classical enough that I thought it might have appeared in some mathematical physics problem already. I would greatly appreciate any guidance.
Thank you

Are you asking for the explicit eigenfunctions?

Might it also have appeared in some probability or statistics problem?

@GiorgioMetafune Yes, if possible. The leading eigenvalue seems to be $1/\sqrt{2}$ and the other ones seem to be of the form $a * b^n$ for some and b. Morally the eigenfunctions should be of the form $Q(x)\exp^{-x^2/2}$ where Q is a sub-exponential function.
I'm mostly hoping that someone from statistical physics stumbled upon this operator in the past and studied it.

@MichaelHardy That's my hope yes. This operator appeared when trying to find the invariant distribution of a rather vanilla version of a Random walk on an interval.

@martintassy Concerning notation: the $\exp$ notation was introduced precisely for the purpose of making it unnecessary to use a superscript when the superscript is a long complicated thing. Thus $\displaystyle \exp\left( \frac 1 \alpha\int \sum \cdots\cdots+\cdots\cdots \right)$ versus $e^{\frac1\alpha\int\sum\cdots\cdots + \cdots\cdots}.$

Suppose $Y$ is a random variable with a normal (or "Gaussian", if you like) distribution with expected value $-x$ and variance $1,$ and $$Y_\text{censored} = \begin{cases} Y & \text{if } Y>0, \ 0 & \text{if } Y<0. \end{cases} $$ Then we have $$ f(x) = \sqrt{2\pi} \operatorname E\left( f(Y_\text{censored}) \right). $$

@MichaelHardy Yes, this is more or less how the operator appeared in the first place. If you take a distribution $\mu$ on the half real line and do a standard normal jump with a reflection at 0. Then $T\mu$ represents the mass that "bounced" on the zero wall. The look of the operator seem so vanilla though that I'm hoping it already appeared in other contexts.

The first eigenfunction seems to be $\exp(-x^2/2)$ and numerically it looked like the other ones are probably something like $p(x)\exp(-x^2/2)$ for some polynomial $p$, but this seems to be wrong…

@Dirk: I don't think $e^{-x^2/2}$ can be an eigenfunction. That would mean that $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-xy-y^2}, dy =\lambda$, but clearly the integral is not independent of $x$.
